# Output in JTextFiled which can keep refreshing when each row is read

Tags: java, refresh, jtextfield

I am a beginner in Java and had started writing a program to read text from a file         and want to output each row to `JTextField`.

I want to compare each row of number so I need a field where each row of data keeps refreshing.

I can do it with Visual Basic with loop, Me.refresh, and `system.thread.sleep`. But I need  to achieve it with Java.
I use `System.out.println(num);` which showed all rows of the file.

When I use `textArea.append(num + "\n");` to output it, I only got all rows displayed after it reached the end. `textArea = new JTextArea("",10,30);`

If I use `dataRead.setText(num);` to output it, I only got the last row displayed after it reached the end. `dataRead = new JTextField(7);`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a Swing threading problem where by trying to read in a file in the Swing event thread, you end up tying up the thread, freezing your GUI until the read is complete. I suggest that you create a background thread, such as that provided by a SwingWorker, with which to read in your File, and then after each line, publish the line to the JTextField, and perhaps if you wish, call `Thread.sleep(...)` in your background thread.

An alternative is to read the whole file in in one fell swoop, again in a background thread, but then use a Swing Timer to display each row, one at a time.